# How to add or get a launch path to a product in AWS Service Catalog using Javascript sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-service-catalog

I'm using Javascript SDK of AWS to access Service Catalog in my Lambda function.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ServiceCatalog.html#provisionProduct-property

I have successfully created portfolio and product and attached the product to this portfolio. When I try to provision the product it throws the error "No launch path is found". To get launch path list I hit the listLaunchPath API and it returns empty array with message "No launch path found for this product"

I have explored AWS Docs in detail but did not find any way to set launch path.
Can anybody guide me how to create and get a launch path for a product in AWS service Catalog?

Answer (score 3):

The error message `Unable to launch provisioned product because: No launch paths found for resource` isn't super helpful. It can mean any of the following:

1. The product doesn't exist
2. The provisioning artifact doesn't exist
3. The product exists but it's in a failed state
4. You don't have access to the product
5. You don't have access to the product's portfolio
6. The product isn't associated with a portfolio
7. The launch path does not exist

Since the error message is not helpful, it doesn't tell you which of these are to blame.

To see how unhelpful the error message is, try this for fun:

```
% aws servicecatalog provision-product --provisioned-product-name no --product-id nope --provisioning-artifact-id nopity-nope

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the ProvisionProduct operation: No launch paths found for resource: nope
```

Some pointers to getting it to work:

- Associate the product to a portfolio.
- Associate a principal that is or includes you to the portfolio.
- Make sure the product is properly created by not using `DisableTemplateValidation`. When you create the product, you'll get an error if the template has an error.
- Try describing the provisioning artifact to make sure it exists.
- Try describing the product. If you can describe the product, it exists, and you have access. You should see a launch path as part of the product description. If you can describe the product but it doesn't have a launch path, I suspect the template is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add IAM Role/User/Group to portfolio where your product is attached to.
Use the Role/User/Group Creds to list launch path. It works